# Exibir os dados do Arrays Itens

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Model do json:

```
class ListaPedido {
  int numero;
  String localEntrega;
  String dataHora;
  String formaPagamento;
  List<ItensPed> itens;

  ListaPedido({
    this.numero,
    this.localEntrega,
    this.dataHora,
    this.formaPagamento,
    this.itens,
  });

  ListaPedido.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    numero = json['numero'];
    localEntrega = json['local_entrega'];
    dataHora = json['data_hora'];
    formaPagamento = json['forma_pagamento'];
    if (json['Itens'] != null) {
      itens = new List<ItensPed>();
      json['Itens'].forEach((v) {
        itens.add(new ItensPed.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['numero'] = this.numero;
    data['local_entrega'] = this.localEntrega;
    data['data_hora'] = this.dataHora;
    data['forma_pagamento'] = this.formaPagamento;
    if (this.itens != null) {
      data['Itens'] = this.itens.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class ItensPed {
  String peduuid;
  String itemUid;
  String qtde;
  String valor;
  String valorTotal;
  String descrProduto;
  String tamanho;
  String textoOpc;

  ItensPed({
    this.peduuid,
    this.itemUid,
    this.qtde,
    this.valor,
    this.valorTotal,
    this.descrProduto,
    this.tamanho,
    this.textoOpc,
  });

  ItensPed.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    peduuid = json['peduuid'];
    itemUid = json['item_uid'];
    qtde = json['qtde'];
    valor = json['valor'];
    valorTotal = json['valor_total'];
    descrProduto = json['descr_produto'];
    tamanho = json['tamanho'];
    textoOpc = json['texto_opc'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['peduuid'] = this.peduuid;
    data['item_uid'] = this.itemUid;
    data['qtde'] = this.qtde;
    data['valor'] = this.valor;
    data['valor_total'] = this.valorTotal;
    data['descr_produto'] = this.descrProduto;
    data['tamanho'] = this.tamanho;
    data['texto_opc'] = this.textoOpc;
    return data;
  }
}
```

API via post onde to pegando os dados:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cardapiomonitor/api/listar_pedido.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ListarPedidoApi {
  static Future<List<ListaPedido>> getListarPedido(String ppeduuid) async {
    var url = "http://192.168.1.12/api/ws_acoes.php";

    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: <String, String>{
        'pedido': ppeduuid,
        'requisicao': 'LISTARPEDIDO',
      },
    );

    List listaResponseLP = json.decode(response.body);

    final listarpedidos = List<ListaPedido>();

    for (Map mapLP in listaResponseLP) {
      ListaPedido lp = ListaPedido.fromJson(mapLP);
      listarpedidos.add(lp);
    }

    return listarpedidos;
  }
}
```

Quero exibir o dados desse array:

```
[
    {
        "numero": 722,
        "local_entrega": "Retirar no local",
        "data_hora": "2021-01-15 15:54:29",
        "forma_pagamento": "Dinheiro",
        "Itens": [
            {
                "item_uid": "4022acfe-f7cf-462d-b8bb-069a61cd8a9e",
                "qtde": "1.00",
                "valor": "2.00",
                "valor_total": "2.00",
                "descr_produto": "2-teste",
                "tamanho": "",
                "peduuid": "763145db-1610-4e71-9871-aeeecec1825a",
                "texto_opc": "Sem opcionais"
            },
            {
                "item_uid": "028c0f84-fa78-4685-9168-9ac5a24d0035",
                "qtde": "1.00",
                "valor": "29.99",
                "valor_total": "29.99",
                "descr_produto": "1-SUSHI",
                "tamanho": "",
                "peduuid": "763145db-1610-4e71-9871-aeeecec1825a",
                "texto_opc": "Sem opcionais"
            },
            {
                "item_uid": "574aed5e-033e-4fab-9d4b-dfc78f73669b",
                "qtde": "1.00",
                "valor": "3.00",
                "valor_total": "3.00",
                "descr_produto": "4-Porção de Batata Frita",
                "tamanho": "",
                "peduuid": "763145db-1610-4e71-9871-aeeecec1825a",
                "texto_opc": "Sem opcionais"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como exibir esse json, principalmente os itens???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou dar um exemplo de um JSON no mesmo formato que o seu "item > sub-itens", daí você implementa pro teu caso...

Vou utilizar o seguinte JSON:

```
    {
       "usuarios":[
          {
             "id":"001",
             "nome":"Matheus Ribeiro",
             "telefone":"5514981234567",
             "emails":[
                {
                   "email":"contato@matheus.com",
                   "tipo":"contato"
                },
                {
                   "email":"financeiro@matheus.com",
                   "tipo":"financeiro"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "id":"002",
             "nome":"Miranda",
             "telefone":"5514981765432",
             "emails":[
                {
                   "email":"contato@miranda.com",
                   "tipo":"contato"
                },
                {
                   "email":"financeiro@miranda.com",
                   "tipo":"financeiro"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

---

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

  final String json = 
    """
    {
       "usuarios":[
          {
             "id":"001",
             "nome":"Matheus Ribeiro",
             "telefone":"5514981234567",
             "emails":[
                {
                   "email":"contato@matheus.com",
                   "tipo":"contato"
                },
                {
                   "email":"financeiro@matheus.com",
                   "tipo":"financeiro"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "id":"002",
             "nome":"Miranda",
             "telefone":"5514981765432",
             "emails":[
                {
                   "email":"contato@miranda.com",
                   "tipo":"contato"
                },
                {
                   "email":"financeiro@miranda.com",
                   "tipo":"financeiro"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
    """;
  
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

 final jsonMap = jsonDecode(json);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Usuario> usuarios = (jsonMap["usuarios"] as List).map((usuario) => Usuario.fromJson(usuario as Map<String, dynamic> )).toList();
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: usuarios.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        Usuario usuario = usuarios[index];
        return Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
                Text("${usuario.id} - ${usuario.nome}"),
                Column(
                 children: usuario.emails.map((email) {
                    return Text("${email.email} (${email.tipo})");
                 }).toList(),
                )
            ],
         )
        );
      }
    );
  }
}

class Email {
  Email({this.email, this.tipo});

  final String email;
  final String tipo;
  
  factory Email.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Email(
    email: json["email"] as String,
    tipo: json["tipo"]  as String);
}

class Usuario {
  Usuario({this.id, this.nome, this.telefone, this.emails});
 
  final String id;
  final String nome;
  final String telefone;
  final List<Email> emails;
  
  factory Usuario.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Usuario(
    id: json["id"] as String,
    nome: json["nome"] as String,
    telefone: json["telefone"] as String,
    emails: (json["emails"] as List).map((conteudo) => Email.fromJson(conteudo as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList());
}
```

> Você pode rodar esse código no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter)

Você pode também dar uma olhada no meu artigo [Descomplicando o JSON em Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-comunidade-br/descomplicando-o-json-em-flutter-47e12b87753b)

Comment: vlw Matheus, deu certo aqui, só tive que modificar algumas coisas pois estava pegando via post, mas deu certo, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Se ajudou resolver teu problema e não quer aguardar outras respostas, lembre-se de marcar como aceita a resposta.